# How can I get many-to-many as array with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm working on a project (transform code and data from C#, SQL to Golang, MongoDB). I have a database with some many-to-many tables relation like:

Just concept for simplicity:

```
table main {
    mid,
    mx,
    my
}

table mb {
    mid,
    bid
}

table b {
    bid,
    bdata
}
```

I need to export main table to object (json) like:

```
{
    mid,
    mx,
    my,
    b: Array[bdata]
}
```

and also in another tables with same schema needed to join main and b table but only most recent b record ( base on bigest b.bid ) and skip old ones.

I need help/guidance with Linq query which cover those two scenarios.

Comment: Take a look at [Group Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx)

Comment: See following webpage for some good samples of Linq Join statements : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b